# how to pass float argument in predict function in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn

I was following a course on machine learning where the instructor passes a float argument in predict function for polynomial linear regression and it works for him. However, when I pass the code it throws an error stating

> "Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead".

I have tried to use the scalar into an array but it does not seem to work.

```
# Polynomial Regression

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
"""from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)"""

# Feature Scaling
"""from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc_X.transform(X_test)"""

# Fitting Linear Regression to the dataset
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X, y)

# Fitting Polynomial Regression to the dataset
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 4)
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X)
poly_reg.fit(X_poly, y)
lin_reg_2 = LinearRegression()
lin_reg_2.fit(X_poly, y)



# Predicting a new result with Linear Regression
lin_reg.predict(6.5)
```

The code seems to run smoothly for the instructor. However, I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
>   array=6.5.
>   Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

[This is the error that I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CH0n.png)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the predict function accepts 2D array as an input, so u can put 6.5 inside big brackets like this [[6.5]]

```
lin_reg.predict([[6.5]])
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow! You're more likely to get your question answered with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and show at least a portion of any required external files. In this case, I think I've boiled it down to the essentials:

```
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
salaries = [('Junior', 1, 50000),
            ('Associate', 2, 60000),
            ('Senior', 3, 70000),
            ('Manager', 4, 80000)]
df = pd.DataFrame(salaries)
X = df.iloc[:, 1:2].values
y = df.iloc[:, 2].values

# Fitting Linear Regression to the dataset
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X, y)

# Predicting a new result with Linear Regression
print(lin_reg.predict(6.5))
```

Although I can't be sure exactly what is in the Position_Salaries.csv, I assume based on other arguments that it looks something like what I've shown. Running that example returns the expected result of 76100 in python 3.6 with sklearn 0.19. If you still get an error, try updating sklearn

> pip update sklearn

If you're still getting an error after that, not sure where the difference is, but you can spoof a 2d array by passing the argument like this: `lin_reg.predict([[6.5]])`